# Windirstat equivalent daemon for Linux server?

Tags: linux, monitoring, daemon, disk-space-utilization

Is there a daemon-type application for Linux, that runs in the background, periodically maintaining a windirstat-type picture of the file system?

Ideally it would have its own web interface, but I could obviously hack one together in PHP if not.

Oh, and it would have to run on ultra-low IO priority. I don't want my disks getting thrashed either, for fear of shortening their lives.

Comment: Consider looking at Alternativeto.net to answer what is equivalent of -program- for -other-OS-.

Comment: That's a great site, thanks for the link. However, what I want isn't a carbon copy (that would be KDirstat which already exists). I want a server daemon that generates an image for later display.

Comment: How about `munin`? If you'd like, I'll write up an answer on that.

Comment: I'd heard of munin. It's not exactly what I'm looking for so don't bother putting it in an answer, but it is definitely a good program.